# Add a warning directive at the top of every page on a Sphinx RTD site

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I'd like to add a simple warning directive at the top of every page on a Sphinx RTD site:

```
.. attention::

  The next major release of this project will launch on X date.
  In the meantime, we're looking for feedback.
  If you'd like an early preview, please reach out at someemail@someaddress.com!
```

What's the simplest way to do this? I'm using the `sphinx_rtd_theme`.

I can see how to add a block using the `extrabody` block, but it appears outside the main content area and is positioned and styled totally independently.

Ideally, I'd want this block to show up at an attention directive just below the breadcrumbs on every page.

Comment: Here's other examples to consider: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/ and https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.9-branch/ You could either edit the theme with actual HTML, or you put that reStructuredText into an included file, and add an `include` directive at the top of each .rst file. Not the prettiest method, but it would get the job done.

Answer (score 4):

You could add this to the `conf.py` Sphinx configuration file:

```
rst_prolog = """.. attention::
    The next major release is imminent.
"""
```

and it will be included at the beginning of every source file that is read ‒ see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-rst_prolog.

F-string literals work too, so `f'This is release #{release}'` will substitute that variable value.

Comment: Also, some themes include this functionality, e.g. "announcement banners" in [sphinx-book-theme](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customize/announcements.html)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the advice anyone wants to hear. But... consider **switching to another theme** that supports common functionality like this out-of-the-box: e.g.,

- [`pydata-sphinx-theme`](https://pydata-sphinx-theme.readthedocs.io/en/v0.12.0/user_guide/announcements.html), widely used throughout the open-source data science community. This includes NumPy and SciPy. It doesn't get bigger than that. Personally, I recently switched a [*sorta* popular project I maintain](https://beartype.readthedocs.io) from [Furo](https://pradyunsg.me/furo/) (*...which I strongly advise against, as it's even less configurable than the `sphinx-rtd-theme` you're currently using*) to `pydata-sphinx-theme`. I wish I'd switched sooner. `pydata-sphinx-theme` single-handedly catapults Sphinx to the upper crust of the documentation generation community. It's so expert at everything that I *kinda* wish Sphinx just bundled `pydata-sphinx-theme` as its default theme. Seriously. That would've saved me a great deal of grief. Why bother with anything else in 2023 and beyond?
- [`sphinx-book-theme`](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/customize/announcements.html), which is actually built on top of `pydata-sphinx-theme`. It's `pydata-sphinx-theme++`, effectively. If you know one, you know the other.

Both trivialize the injection of arbitrary HTML (referred to as an "announcement") at the top of every page:

```py
# In your project's equivalent of "docs/conf.py":
html_theme_options = {
    # Announcement banner defined as a string of arbitrary HTML, temporarily
    # displayed at the top of each page until the user begins scrolling.
    'announcement': (
        "<p>"
        "Here's a <a href='https://pydata.org'>PyData Announcement!</a>"
        "</p>"
    ),

    ...
}
```

HTML is *much* more useful than mere reStructuredText (reST) in this context of a project banner. HTML admits the possibility of exotic use cases like project-specific advertising – which almost certainly violates the Terms of Services on free-as-in-beer Sphinx hosts like ReadTheDocs (RTD), so please avoid abusing this there. Still, this feature is pretty much the Ultimate Power for informing users about... well, *anything!*

### But, But... What About `rst_prolog`?

**Yeah.** Don't do that. Technically, you *can* force-feed an announcement at the top or bottom of every page [by abusing Sphinx's standard `rst_prolog` and `rst_epilog` globals as in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62022328/2809027). Pragmatically, doing so doesn't actually produce a hero banner; it's just a crude hack.

You ideally want your announcement to be an actual *banner* that sprawls across the full horizontal width of each page. But the output produced by the `rst_prolog` and `rst_epilog` globals is almost always confined to the central column of your theme. It just looks like any other normal page content. It's certainly better than nothing, but announcements are intended to immediately draw the eye. So, do so!

In short, may the PyData be with you always. `\o/`